# How I can resolve the problem of conversion (to_integer(unsigned(variable))

Tags: vhdl, vga, quartus

I want to solve a problem in VHDL with Quartus II.

I made a model of VGA protocol 640/480. When I made the part of displaying 
I made one two signal in integer.

> Error (10621): VHDL Use Clause error at dispGest.vhd(28): more than
>   one Use Clause imports a declaration of simple name "unsigned" -- none
>   of the declarations are directly visible

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Delete one of the Use clauses. Preferably the non-standard one.

Answer (score 2):

Adding numeric_std library, you can declare signed and unsigned variables.
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

Answer (score 0):

A search show this error code isn't addressed on EESE.

IEEE Std 1076-2008
12.4 Use clauses

> A use clause achieves direct visibility of declarations that are visible by selection.
>   ...
>   In order to determine which declarations are made directly visible at a given place by use clauses, consider the set of declarations identified by all use clauses whose scopes enclose this place. Any declaration in this set is a potentially visible declaration. A potentially visible declaration is actually made directly visible except in the following three cases:
>
> > a) A potentially visible declaration is not made directly visible if the place considered is within the immediate scope of a homograph of the declaration.
> >
> > b) If two potentially visible declarations are homographs and one is explicitly declared and the other is implicitly declared, then the implicit declaration is not made directly visible.
> >
> > **c) Potentially visible declarations that have the same designator and that are not covered by case b) are not made directly visible unless each of them is either an enumeration literal specification or the declaration of a subprogram.**

There's also

12.3 Visibility, paragraph 7 (in part)

> ...Each of two declarations is said to be a *homograph* of the other if and only if both declarations have the same designator, and they denote different named entities, and either overloading is allowed for at most one of the two, or overloading is allowed for both declarations and they have the same parameter and result type profile (see 4.5.1).

that defines homograph and

6. Declarations, 6.1 General paragraph 3

> For each form of declaration, the language rules define a certain region of text called the *scope* of the declaration (see 12.2). Each form of declaration associates an identifier, operator symbol, or character literal with a named entity. The identifier, operator symbol, or character literal is called the *designator* of the declaration. Only within its scope, there are places where it is possible to use the designator to refer to the associated declared entity; these places are defined by the visibility rules (see 12.3). At such places the designator is said to be a *name* of the entity; the name is said to *denote* the associated entity.

which defines *designator*.

For the particular error

> Error (10621): VHDL Use Clause error at dispGest.vhd(28): more than one Use Clause imports a declaration of simple name "unsigned" -- none of the declarations are directly visible

and for the set of use clauses:

```vhdl
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
```

Both package numeric_std and package std_logic_arith provide declarations for type unsigned. They represent distinct named entities:

6.2 Type declarations

> The types created by the elaboration of distinct type definitions are distinct types. ...

The two declarations of unsigned are homographs having the same designator, b) above is not applicable both are explicitly declared.

The two declarations of unsigned are homographs having the same designator, b) above is not applicable both are explicitly declared.

Both package std_logic_arith and numeric_std provide declarations for type unsigned:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;      -- to_integer conversion function
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;  -- also declares type unsigned

entity dispgest_mcve is
end entity;

architecture foo of dispgest_mcve is
    signal some_integer:    integer;
    signal some_slv:        std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    process
    begin
        some_integer <= to_integer(unsigned(some_slv));
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

which isn't made visible:

```
ghdl -a --ieee=synopsys dispgest_mcve.vhdl
dispgest_mcve.vhdl:15:36:error: no declaration for "unsigned" (due to conflicts)
ghdl:error: compilation error
```

Here using ghdl, whose error message delivers the same information, neither error message specifying the package name.

Commenting out the use clause making declarations from Synopsys package std_logic_arith visible results in:

```
ghdl -a dispgest_mcve.vhdl
ghdl -e dispgest_mcve
ghdl -r dispgest_mcve
```

no errors.